# Conventions of notation regarding $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{++}$

Tags: notation, convention

I have seen $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ used to denote both of the sets

$$\mathbb{R}_{+}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\ge0\}$$
$$\mathbb{R}_{+}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\gt0\}$$

In order to avoid confusion, some authors have adopted the notation
$$\mathbb{R}_{++}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\gt0\}$$

Is one notation more prevalent than the others, and thus safer to assume? My guess is that different countries use different conventions, but I have not been able to find any patterns in literature.

What do you take it to mean when you see $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, assuming that it cannot be easily inferred from the case (e.g. the domain of $\log(x)$)?

Comment: I have never seen it with double $+$ signs. Rather so $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ to say that $x\ge 0$ and without $0$ to say $x>0$

Comment: I haven't often seen $\Bbb R_+$ to indicate $[0, \infty)$, but I have seen the (slightly clumsy but unambiguous) $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$. I have never see the $\cdot_{++}$ notation either.